# Declare pointer for nested struct

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I am new to c++ and I have encountered some questions for nested struct.
For example: I have the struct like this: and I want to declare a pointer for this struct.

```
struct person{
     int year;
     char name[20];
     bool available;
};

struct data{
      int list;
      person number;
};

int main(){
    data *ptr;
    data notptr[3];
    ptr = &notptr;
}
```

and then I compile it and received message like this:

```
cannot covert 'data(*)[3]' to 'data' in assignment 
ptr = &notptr;
    ^
```

Please help me with that. I have been using one hour to figure it out but still dont know why..

Thank you very much.

For this program, I am trying to read file into struct using pointer.

Comment: `ptr = notptr;`, or equivalently, but perhaps more clearly: `ptr = &notptr[0];`

Comment: The compiler message is very clear. `&notptr` is a pointer to an array of 3 objects while `ptr` is pointer to an object. Hence, you cannot assign `&notptr` to `ptr`. Please explain what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I am trying to read file into structs using pointer for this program

Comment: I tried ptr = &notptr[0]; that works . Thank you!

Comment: For the record, the term "nested struct" is normally used differently. It refers to a struct defined inside another type's definition. For example, `std::string::size_type` is a nested type defined in `std::string`.

Comment: @RSahu +1 for the comment. Also note that, we can use casting to solve the issue gracefully: `ptr = reinterpret_cast<data*>(&notptr);` or `ptr = (data*)&notptr;`

Answer (score 1):

You can not do assignment like `ptr = &notptr` because `&notptr` is a pointer to 3 objects whereas `ptr` is pointer to a single object.

You can only do this way `ptr = &notptr[index];`